# Can't Create a new laravel app

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

Am trying to create a new laravel project, in the past i have successfully created a new laravel project by running `laravel new blog`, i just tried it about 2hrs ago and i get this error.

```
nkossy Desktop $ laravel new blog
Crafting application...
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
   - Installation request for symfony/thanks v1.0.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/thanks[v1.0.1].
   - symfony/thanks v1.0.1 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.1 -> no matching package found.
Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
Application ready! Build something amazing.
```

am running Ubuntu 16.04 with php7.1 installation
Running `composer update` doesn't help

Comment: Looks like `"symfony/thanks": "^1.0"` was introduced a couple of days ago, https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commit/60de3a5670c4a3bf5fb96433828b6aadd7df0e53, that package looks like a way to boost/spam github stars, kinda pointless and abit PUP

Answer (score 0):

Remove "symphony/thanks" dependency in your project's composer.json plugin and run 'composer update' after.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what I did.

- First, uninstall composer, Follow instructions [here](https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/xenial/composer?action=remove)
- then reinstall composer by running the following command.

`curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer`

Lastly run `laravel new app`, done.